# Strange graphics issue with Windows 7 - multiple user accounts

Tags: windows-7, technical-issues

I've bought a copy of 1701 Gold Edition. It installed fine on my main account, an administrator account with UAC. But when my son tries on his non admin account, the trees are drawn wrong! Really big and sheared - making it impossible to play.

Its the same for my wife'a account which is also an admin account - the trees are drawn wrong.

I just find it totally weird that the game will is OK on one account and on others has serious graphics issues...

It kind of suggests a problem in windows rather than the game itself.

Anybody got any thoughts, or managed to cure a similar problem?

---

Repsonses:
The Graphics Card is an ATI Radion HD 3600 - driver up to date.

One test I did was to add a completely new user - it works.

---

On My Account:
[image]

On my Son's account, similar on my wife's account too:
[image]

Comment: Do you have integrated graphics (video output on the motherboard) or a separate graphics card? If the latter, what's the card make and model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to reinstall the newest grafics driver. If it asks `install for all users` set it to true. I guess you installed the grafics driver as your user. I don´t know if that really is the cause of this issue but I guess it´s worth a try. ;-)

Pleas give an update if it worked. If not I´m going to think again.

Comment: Interesting idea - graphics drivers usually install for all users - but definitely worth a check.

Comment: None of the drivers ATI/Nvidia deliver are user mode ones, so they apply on the system level.

Comment: done that - same problem :-(

Comment: Just read the Windows 7 driver install instructions on the AMD site - the only step i didnt do was un-install the old drivers: I will try that tonight - I'd have thought the upgrade would have done it all - but its worth a try.

Comment: i've used the ATI uninstaller and removed all the components, reboot. I noticed that an ATI dispaly driver is still installed, but no Catalyst Control Centre etc...Just on the off chance, tried running the game again - VOILÀ Trees! never been quite sure what the CCC did... so i'm going to leave it off!

Comment: CCC is the ATi Utility for deeper managing of the grafics card functions.

Comment: I'll tip on the AI feature turned on in the CCC. Good to hear it's resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the game needs to be installed separately for each account? You could try installing it from your son's account.

Also I'd check for updates to the game itself; make sure it is the latest version.

Comment: latest version 1.4 is installed.